# How to select 1st row from table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I want to select first row from table data when page first loads. My `$('#Home').on('click', '#tblStyles .HomeSelect', function () {` does not hit. Please suggest me here I am going wrong.

Report View

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Home">Home</a></li>          
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="Home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Home.cshtml", Model.clsHome)
            </div>

        </div>
```

Home View

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <table id="tblStyles" class="table table-hover">
            <tr class="no-hover" style="border-top:hidden">
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductName)
                </th>            

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="HomeSelect" data-productcode="@item.ProductCode">

                    <td align="right">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
        {
            <div id="mypartial"> </div>

        }
```

Scripts

```
   $(document).ready(function () {             
            $('#Home').find('#tblStyles tr:first').addClass("selected").click();              
        });

     $('#Home').on('click', '#tblStyles .HomeSelect', function () {

            var id = $(this).data('productcode');
```

Comment: You have an extra `{` in `addClass({"selected")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry, I removed that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please guide me where I am going wrong. Why my second script does not hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery selector `$('#Home').find('#tblStyles tr:first')` will give you the first table row. That does not mean that it is the first table row with the CSS class `HomeSelect`. Infact your selector will give you the first row, which is the table header (Where you are calling the `DisplayNameFor` helper method.

Your `click` event handler is wired up for elements with `HomeSelect` CSS Class. So make sure when you invoke the first tr's click event, you follow the same pattern.

Make sure you are invoking the `click` event using JavaScript **after** wiring up the click event handler. I suggest you wire up any event handlers inside the jquery `ready` event.

```
$(function () {
    $('#Home').on('click', '#tblStyles .HomeSelect', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('productcode');
        alert(id);
    });

    // Invoke click on the first row with "HomeSelect" CSS class
    // The header row does not have that class.
    $('#Home').find('#tblStyles tr.HomeSelect:first').click();  
});
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that OP was triggering the `.click()` event before the `.click()` handler had actually been added (swapping the order of the scripts as you have done solves that)

Comment: I had that in the original version. Will add that as well.